# Select Option list Onchange event is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, select

I am trying get value using select option list but it is not called at all. even with alert is not catchup means there is event is not calling please let me know why?

## View

```
@model ApplicationName.Areas.Admin.Models.MenuModel
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Menu Manager";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    string AlternateRow = string.Empty;

    string SuccessMessage = string.Empty;

    int Counter = 0;

    int TotalRecords = 0;

    int PageSize = Constant.PageSize;

    int CurrPage = Constant.CurrPage;

    int PageLimit = Constant.PageLimit;

    string [] NumberOfRows = new string[5];

    string IsActive = "false";

    string IsActiveClass = string.Empty;

    string IsActiveTitle = string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["mode"]))
    {
        if (Request["mode"].ToString() == "Add")
        {
            SuccessMessage = "Menu Added Successfully";
        }
        else if (Request["mode"].ToString() == "Update")
        {
            SuccessMessage = "Menu Updated Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            SuccessMessage = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    //Total Count
    if(Model.CountMenu != null)
    {
        TotalRecords = Model.CountMenu;
    }

}

<!-- start content-outer -->
<div id="content-outer">
    <!-- start content -->

    <div id="content">

        <div id="page-heading">
            <h1>Menu Management</h1>
        </div>



        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Menu", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmmenu", name = "frmmenu" }))
        { 

            @Html.Hidden("TotoalRecs", TotalRecords)
            @Html.Hidden("PageSize", PageSize)
            @Html.Hidden("CurrPage", CurrPage)
            @Html.Hidden("PageLimit", PageLimit)

            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="content-table">
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="3" class="sized">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg")" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
                    <th class="topleft"></th>
                    <td id="tbl-border-top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <th class="topright"></th>
                    <th rowspan="3" class="sized">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/side_shadowright.jpg")" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="tbl-border-left"></td>
                    <td>
                        <!--  start content-table-inner ...................................................................... START -->
                        <div id="content-table-inner">

                            <!--  start table-content  -->
                            <div id="table-content">


                                <!--  start message-green -->
                                <div id="divSuccessMessage">
                                @if (Model.ListMenuPoco.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SuccessMessage))
                                { 
                                    <div id="message-green">
                                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="green-left">@SuccessMessage. <a href="@Url.Action("AddEdit", "Menu")">Add New Menu.</a></td>
                                                <td class="green-right"><a class="close-green">
                                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/table/icon_close_green.gif")"   alt="" /></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                }
                                </div>


                                <!--  end message-green -->


                                <!--  start product-table ..................................................................................... -->
                                <div id="divErrMessage">

                                @if (Model.ListMenuPoco.Count > 0)
                                { 
                                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="table-header-check"><a id="toggle-all"></a></th>
                                            <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><span>Menu Title</span></th>

                                            <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><span>Order Number</span></th>
                                            <th class="table-header-options line-left"><span>Options</span></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="4">
                                                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="divMenuList">

                                        @foreach (var objMenuPoco in Model.ListMenuPoco)
                                        {
                                            Counter++;
                                            if (Counter % 2 == 0)
                                            {
                                                AlternateRow = "alternate-row";
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                AlternateRow = string.Empty;
                                            }

                                            //set for active/inactive
                                            if (objMenuPoco.IsActive == true)
                                            {
                                                IsActive = "false";
                                                IsActiveClass = "icon-3 info-tooltip";
                                                IsActiveTitle = "Published";
                                            }
                                            else if (objMenuPoco.IsActive == false)
                                            {
                                                IsActive = "true";
                                                IsActiveClass = "icon-4 info-tooltip";
                                                IsActiveTitle = "UnPublished";
                                            }
                                            else 
                                            {
                                                IsActive = "false";
                                                IsActiveClass = "icon-4 info-tooltip";
                                                IsActiveTitle = "UnPublished";
                                            }


                                            <tr class="@(AlternateRow)">
                                                <td style="width:3.4%;">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="@objMenuPoco.MenuId" /></td>
                                                <td style="width:38.8%;">@(objMenuPoco.MenuTitle)</td>
                                                <td style="width:39%;">@(objMenuPoco.OrderNumber)</td>
                                                <td class="options-width">
                                                    <a href='@Url.Content("~/Admin/Menu/AddEdit/" + objMenuPoco.MenuId + "")' title="Edit Menu" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"></a>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return performdeletemenu('@objMenuPoco.MenuId');" title="Delete Menu" class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>

                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return performstatusmenu('@(IsActive)', '@(objMenuPoco.MenuId)');" title="@(IsActiveTitle)" class="@IsActiveClass"></a>
                                                    @*<a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-4 info-tooltip"></a>*@
                                                    <a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-5 info-tooltip"></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        }
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--  end product-table................................... -->
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <!--  start message-red -->

                                    @Html.Raw(Constant.ErrorMessage);

                                    <!--  end message-red -->
                                }


                            </div>
                            <!--  end content-table  -->



                            <!--  start paging..................................................... -->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="paging-table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td  style="width:48%;">
                                        <!--  start actions-box ............................................... -->
                            <div id="actions-box">
                                <a href="" class="action-slider"></a>
                                <div id="actions-box-slider">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("AddEdit", "Menu")" class="action-edit">Add Menu</a>
                                    <a href="" class="action-edit">Edit</a>

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="action-delete" onclick="return performalldeletemenu();">Delete All</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end actions-box........... -->

                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:42%;">
                                        <table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            @*<td style="width:7%;">
                                                <a href="" class="page-far-left"></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:7%;">
                                                <a href="" class="page-left"></a>
                                            </td>*@
                                            <td style="width:100%;">
                                                    @*<div id="page-info">Page <strong>1</strong> / 15</div>*@
                                        <div id="pager">

                                        </div>
                                            </td>
                                            @*<td style="width:7%;">
                                                <a href="" class="page-right"></a>
                                            </td>*@
                                            @*<td style="width:7%;">
                                                <a href="" class="page-far-right"></a>
                                            </td>*@
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:10%;">

                                        @Html.DropDownList(
                                       "selectedValue", 
                                        Constant.ArrNumberOfRows.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                        Value = x.ToString(),
                                        Text = x.ToString(),
                                        }), 
                                    "Number of rows",
                                        new { 
                                            id = "SelectNumRows", 
                                            @class = "styledselect_pages" 
                                        }
                                    )

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--  end paging................ -->

                            <div class="clear"></div>

                        </div>
                        <!--  end content-table-inner ............................................END  -->
                    </td>
                    <td id="tbl-border-right"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sized bottomleft"></th>
                    <td id="tbl-border-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
                    <th class="sized bottomright"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>


    <!--  end content -->
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--  end content-outer -->


<script type="text/javascript">

    var JsErrorAction = '@Url.Action("Index", "ErrorLog")';
    var JsTokenHeaderValue = '@Utils.TokenHeaderValue()';
    var JsMethodAction = '@Url.Content("~/api/MenuWebApi/DeleteMenu")'; 
    var JsErrorMessage = '@Html.Raw(Common.Constant.ErrorMessage)';

    $(function () {
        $('input').checkBox();
        $('#toggle-all').click(function () {
            $('#toggle-all').toggleClass('toggle-checked');
            $('#frmmenu input[type=checkbox]').checkBox('toggle');
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/admin_menu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

=================

_layout

===========================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")



    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/screen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/pro_dropline_ie.css")" />
<![endif]-->


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui.checkbox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.bind.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>




<![if !IE 7]>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.styledselect').selectbox({ inputClass: "selectbox_styled" });
    });
</script>

<![endif]>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.styledselect_form_1').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_1" });
        $('.styledselect_form_2').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_2" });
    });
</script>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.styledselect_pages').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_pages" });
    });
</script>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.filestyle.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $("input.file_1").filestyle({
            image: "images/forms/upload_file.gif",
            imageheight: 29,
            imagewidth: 78,
            width: 300
        });
    });
</script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom_jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tooltip.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dimensions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@*<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('a.info-tooltip ').tooltip({
            track: true,
            delay: 0,
            fixPNG: true,
            showURL: false,
            showBody: " - ",
            top: -35,
            left: 5
        });
    });
</script> *@

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/datePicker.css")" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/date.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.datePicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function ()
    {

        $('#date-pick')
            .datePicker(
                // associate the link with a date picker
                {
                    createButton: false,
                    startDate: '01/01/2005',
                    endDate: '31/12/2020'
                }
            ).bind(
                // when the link is clicked display the date picker
                'click',
                function () {
                    updateSelects($(this).dpGetSelected()[0]);
                    $(this).dpDisplay();
                    return false;
                }
            ).bind(
                // when a date is selected update the SELECTs
                'dateSelected',
                function (e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
                    updateSelects(selectedDate);
                }
            ).bind(
                'dpClosed',
                function (e, selected) {
                    updateSelects(selected[0]);
                }
            );

        var updateSelects = function (selectedDate) {
            var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            $('#d option[value=' + selectedDate.getDate() + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('#m option[value=' + (selectedDate.getMonth() + 1) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('#y option[value=' + (selectedDate.getFullYear()) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
        }

        $('#d, #m, #y')
            .bind(
                'change',
                function () {
                    var d = new Date(
                                $('#y').val(),
                                $('#m').val() - 1,
                                $('#d').val()
                            );
                    $('#date-pick').dpSetSelected(d.asString());
                }
            );


        var today = new Date();
        updateSelects(today.getTime());


        $('#d').trigger('change');
    });
</script>




</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- Start: page-top-outer -->
<div id="page-top-outer">    

<!-- Start: page-top -->
<div id="page-top">

    <!-- start logo -->
    <div id="logo">

    <a href=""><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/logo.png")" width="156" height="40" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- end logo -->

    <!--  start top-search -->
    <div id="top-search">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="Search" onblur="if (this.value=='') { this.value='Search'; }" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search') { this.value=''; }" class="top-search-inp" /></td>
        <td>

        <select  class="styledselect">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="">Products</option>
            <option value="">Categories</option>
            <option value="">Clients</option>
            <option value="">News</option>
        </select> 

        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/top_search_btn.gif")"  />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--  end top-search -->
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!-- End: page-top -->

</div>
<!-- End: page-top-outer -->

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................................................................. START -->
<div class="nav-outer-repeat"> 
<!--  start nav-outer -->
<div class="nav-outer"> 

        <!-- start nav-right -->
        <div id="nav-right">

            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="showhide-account"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/nav/nav_myaccount.gif")" width="93" height="14" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>
            <a href="" id="logout"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/nav/nav_logout.gif")" width="64" height="14" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

            <!--  start account-content --> 
            <div class="account-content">
            <div class="account-drop-inner">
                <a href="" id="acc-settings">Settings</a>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="acc-line">&nbsp;</div>
                <a href="" id="acc-details">Personal details </a>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="acc-line">&nbsp;</div>
                <a href="" id="acc-project">Project details</a>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="acc-line">&nbsp;</div>
                <a href="" id="acc-inbox">Inbox</a>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="acc-line">&nbsp;</div>
                <a href="" id="acc-stats">Statistics</a> 
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--  end account-content -->

        </div>
        <!-- end nav-right -->


        <!--  start nav -->
        <div class="nav">
        <div class="table">

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Dashboard</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="current"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Menu Management</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Page Management</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>User Management</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Build Type</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Qualification</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>
            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Email Templates</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>
            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>News Letters</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--  start nav -->

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--  start nav-outer -->
</div>
<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................... END -->

        <!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................................................................. START -->
<div class="nav-outer-repeat"> 
<!--  start nav-outer -->
<div class="nav-outer"> 

        <!--  start nav -->
        <div class="nav">
        <div class="table">



        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Enquiry Management</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Reported Problem List</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>
            <div class="nav-divider">&nbsp;</div>

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Advertise Management</b><!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--  start nav -->

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--  start nav-outer -->
</div>
<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................... END -->

 <div class="clear"></div>
        @RenderBody()
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- start footer -->         
<div id="footer">
    <!--  start footer-left -->
    <div id="footer-left">
    Admin Skin &copy; Copyright Internet Dreams Ltd. <a href="">www.netdreams.co.uk</a>. All rights reserved.</div>
    <!--  end footer-left -->
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- end footer -->

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#SelectNumRows").on('change', function () {
        alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
    });

});
```

## Class

```
.styledselect_pages {
    background: url(../images/table/select_number_rows.gif) left no-repeat;
    border: none;
    border-left: none;
    color: #393939;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 4px 0 0 6px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 130px;
    }
```

waiting for response.

Regards

Comment: are you getting any error check console ??

Comment: No, I can not see any error

Comment: Did you include jquery.js in your application before this code?

Comment: simplify the alert, just use `alert('test');` for now

Comment: added jquery-1.8.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js, Not aded jquery.js i need to add?

Comment: No, `jquery-1.8.2.min.js` is fine. Is it included BEFORE your script which is using it?

Comment: Yes, i have added before script, in _layout.cshtml which is the master page. i am not getting why not called, so many times done but since 1 hour not getting

Comment: @christiandev : done as you mentioned but not working still

Comment: Could you show your Layout? And your view?

Comment: I can't understand why you don't have any console errors. If JQuery was not included you should get `$ is not defined` error, if it is included then [it should work](http://jsfiddle.net/DuBh2/)

Comment: because jquery-1.8.2.min.js is added already thats why not any error

Comment: @dotnetexpert do you get alert ??

Comment: @Tushar : no still not..

Comment: @dotnetexpert is your code online ??

Comment: @Tushar : No in localhost.

Comment: even with <select class="styledselect_pages" id="SelectNumRows" oncnage="return CallFunction()" > is not working ..

Comment: It's normal that it's not working. There's no such event: `oncnage`. Also if you put an alert directly inside the document.ready callback is this alert shown?

Comment: @Darin : Sorry not oncnage, but with onchange event is not workng, and as you mentioned , i have done alert is called with document.ready not with select change event

Comment: @dotnetexpert try change this `$("#SelectNumRows")` to `$('select')`

Comment: @Tushar : no still not..

Comment: @Tushar I have added only Jqyer 1.8.2 min.js are you concern with Jquery-ui-1.9 version?

Comment: @dotnetexpert okay check if all files are loaded ?

Comment: @Tushar : loaded all scripts with FF -> Scripts tab..

Comment: @Tushar : please check class i have added to my post, it was creating the issue, after removing event is triggering.

Comment: @dotnetexpert try this code now `$("#SelectNumRows").on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val() + ' ' + $("#SelectNumRows option:selected").text());
});`

Comment: @Tushar: issue solved... the class name had been created the issue name is : styledselect_pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#SelectNumRows").change( function () {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have added jquery-1.8.2.min.js , i need to add jquery.js?

Comment: No, that isn't required.  Can you post all your code for the page?

Comment: Issue is with that class, after removing that class it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

All the `<option>` elements in your `<select>` element have the same value:

```
value=""
```

So when you select some other element in the dropdown you are changing from `""` to `""` which obviously is not changing anything at all. That's why the change event is not triggered. You should assign your option elements different values.

Also you should use the built-in helpers to generate the dropdown and avoid the horrible tag soup you ended up in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "selectedValue", 
    Constant.ArrNumberOfRows.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.ToString(),
        Text = x.ToString(),
    }), 
    "Number of rows",
    new { 
        id = "SelectNumRows", 
        @class = "styledselect_pages" 
    }
)
```

or if you prefer the tag soup:

```
<select class="styledselect_pages" id="SelectNumRows" >
    <option value="">Number of rows</option>
    @{
        NumberOfRows = Constant.ArrNumberOfRows;
        if (NumberOfRows.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows.Length; i++)
            { 
                <option value="@i">@NumberOfRows[i].ToString()</option>        
            }
        }
     }
</select>
```

Bear in mind though that in your tag soup, the `<select>` element doesn't have a name meaning that if this element is inside a form, when this form is submitted you cannot expect to be able to get the selected value on the server.

Comment: After adding razor syntax it is not working even value is added in option list.

Comment: Do you have some other elements with `id="SelectNumRows"` in your DOM? Other than this particular `<select>` element?

Comment: No, not any other element with id = "SelectNumRows"

Comment: No more clues. Posting the full code of your Layout and view might reveal something else.

Comment: You seem to have included jquery twice. Once with `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and then manually with `jquery-1.8.2.min.js`. You should either use the bundling mechanism built in ASP.NET MVC or manually include your scripts but never mix both.

Comment: commented line but still event is not triggered .@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@

Comment: Me neither, I would try narrowing it down by removing sections of the code.

Comment: if i remove @class = "styledselect_pages"  that class it is working and event is triggering.  I am adding this class attribute to my post.what is the issue with that class

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you have some other javascript which is doing something to elements with this class. It looks like you are using some `selectbox` plugin and have applied it to the dropdown. Maybe this plugin is modifying the structure of the DOM elements and they are no longer select and options. It replaced them with divs or something for which there's no notion of onchange of course. You might consult the documentation of the plugin you are using.

Comment: Darin : Ok, Thanks for your help and time.. it's pleasure for me, you have spend time for me

Comment: Darin : I have posted one question over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280758/mvc4-petapoco-like-query-throwing-exception but i am not getting quick answer : if you have any idea can you please let me know. i have to add comment here even it is different question sorry for it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#SelectNumRows").on('change', function () {
            alert('The option with value ' + $(this).children("option:selected").val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: The problem is not with getting the value. The code shown in the question should work perfectly fine

Comment: Issue is with that class, after removing that class it is working fine.