# mvc4 PetaPoco like query throwing exception

Tags: c#, search, petapoco, sql-like

I am using petapoco. and making search query with like

please let me know there is right query or not?

```
var context = new PetaPoco.Database(Connection.connectionstring);

            SqlQuery =

            @"SELECT MenuId, MenuTitle, OrderNumber, CreatedDate, IsActive
            from Menu
            where MenuTitle LIKE @0, '%@MenuTitle%'";

            List<MenuPOCO> objMenuPoco = context.Query<MenuPOCO>
                (
                SqlQuery,
                new
                {
                    @MenuTitle = MenuTitle

                }).ToList();

            return objMenuPoco;
```

please let me know the syntax is right? I am getting 0 records in each search.

Regards

Comment: Ok got now. Correct is :  List<MenuPOCO> objMenuPoco = context.Query<MenuPOCO>("SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE MenuTitle LIKE @0", "%" + MenuTitle + "%").ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
var context = new PetaPoco.Database(Connection.connectionstring);

        SqlQuery =

        @"SELECT MenuId, MenuTitle, OrderNumber, CreatedDate, IsActive
        from Menu
        where MenuTitle LIKE @0";

        List<MenuPOCO> objMenuPoco = context.Query<MenuPOCO>(SqlQuery, "%" + MenuTitle + "%").ToList();

        return objMenuPoco;
```

Comment: see actual query i want to run this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402194/peta-poco-like-query-issue