# Web-Api 400 BadRequest when search parameter is blank

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-400

I am using web-api with mvc4

I am making searching functionality, in some cases like if i filter data then remove that textbox value and then press search button, need to show whole listing but in my case showing 400 bad request. as search parameter is blank, i know if search parameter blank then it will throw 400 error with web-api.

any one have proper solution then please let me know.

```
data: "CurrPage=" + JsCurrPage + "&PageSize=" + parseInt(pagesize) + "&BuildTypeName=" + $("#BuildTypeName").val(),
```

Here in some cases BuildType is blank. when search made

//controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetBuildTypeList(int CurrPage, int PageSize, string BuildTypeName)
        {

        }
```

Net -> XHR URL is :

```
http://{parentURL}/api/BuildTypeWebApi/GetBuildTypeList?CurrPage=1&PageSize=10&BuildTypeName=
```

Comment: Post the content of the 400

Comment: means ? when my string BuildTypeName is null then it is throwing exception 400 error

Comment: @tom : My post updated

Comment: just post all your code, it's too difficult to understand what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetBuildTypeList(string BuildTypeName, int CurrPage = 1, int PageSize = 0)
```

In you business logic you can assume that a PageSize of 0 means all records.

Comment: string BuildTypeName is searching parameter and if it null then 400 bad reuqest arised, i have done like also string BuildTypeName = null but still 400 error, waiting for your response.

Comment: Make the call in fiddler and let us know what the response contains

Comment: response is 400 Bad request.

Comment: why it is not working even i have defined web-api method string BuildType= "" ?

Comment: Web api is usually helpful enough to provide info about what is missing. you should include that

Answer (score 0):

If you allow CurrPage and PageSize to be empty, then you need to accept nullable ints:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetBuildTypeList(int? CurrPage, int? PageSize, string BuildTypeName)
```

Then, you'll update the query so it return the entire list if no filter values are provided.

Comment: string BuildTypeName is searching parameter and if it null then 400 bad reuqest arised, i have done like also string BuildTypeName = null but still 400 error, waiting for your response.

Comment: Can you try removing "BuildTypeName" and see what you get? http://{parentURL}/api/BuildTypeWebApi/GetBuildTypeList?CurrPage=1&PageSize=10

Comment: same 400 bad reuqest because my controller method need build type name parameter as well, i have tried as you mentioned but it is also throwing 400 bad request, JFI - 400 bad request only when value is blank or parameter mismatch, so solution need to think at that way..